# Only One FileWriter Instance per BufferedWriter Instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, io, bufferedwriter

I am creating a file writing/reading utility for a project in Java. I created a class that encapsulates the general read, write, etc., types of functions for a particular file. The class that will use this file utility is multi-threaded. Inside of that class I have an instance variable for a `FileWriter` (and `FileReader`) object. It is initialized at the construction of this class. Inside of each writing method I create a new instance of a `BufferedWriter` object to pass the `FileWriter` instance to. Is there any reason why I shouldn't do this? Is it necessary that each `BufferedWriter` instance needs a unique `FileWriter` instance? Or am I able to use that same `FileWrite` instance amongst many different `BufferedWriter` instances?

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why you think you need this, but you don't. What you *should* do is create a *single* `BufferedWriter` around the `FileWriter`, and have your methods write to that, subject to synchronization of course.

One of the many problems with multiple `BufferedWriters` is that if you close any of them, the underlying `FileWriter` gets closed too.

Comment: The reason I saw the "need" to do this was to reduce the amount of duplicate code.

Comment: *What* duplicate code? `bufferedWriter.write()?` The fact is that you would be *adding* duplicate code, specifically `new BufferedWriter(...)` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using a BufferedWriter is to buffer data to minimise the number of system calls.  This is done for efficiency purposes, but it works by delaying/batching writes into the Writer it wraps.

In short,

- it's purpose is to improve performance
- it has the downside that what you write to it is not written immediately, and if done incorrectly, never.

Creating multiple BufferedWriters is about the worst thing you can do because;

- its expensive to create, the buffer is 8 KB by default.  Do this often enough and it would easily be worse than not having the buffer at all.
- if you don't flush the data, anything buffered could be lost, or if you have multiple buffers at once, they can be written in any order. It's a great way to corrupt your file. Again, you would be better off not having the buffer than doing this.

A Writer (or any class) is not like fairy dust you sprinkle around to make your code better. It serves a purpose, and you should only add it when you know it is helping.